# np.nanmean not working within a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, mean, nan

A beginner's question:I'm trying to calculate the mean in a column from a dataframe, but for some reason, despite using np.nanmean, it's giving me the wrong result (i.e. it's counting the zeros within the denominator).

As I don't know how to paste in tables into this question (any advice would be great!), here's an example of the issue I'm having:

```
22.0
0
0
0
35
```

This should give me a mean of 28.5, but when I put in:

```
np.nanmean(df)
```

It returns only 11.4.

Now I've experimented with axis settings, and also trying to set my 0s as numpy NaNs, but neither has appeared to work.

Besides doing this manually, is there something straightforward i'm neglecting within the numpy / panda libraries?

Comment: you are fundamentally misunderstanding nan, which means "not a number" like missing data or the result of an invalid operation (e.g. divide by zero).  Zero is a valid number (like black is a valid color, I guess ;-)  admittedly, zeroes can be interpreted as false by python when numbers are implicitly treated as booleans, but generally speaking, zeroes are valid numbers, and certainly are considered valid for any numerical methods like mean, max, etc.

Comment: Hi JohnE - it's a very fair point you make. I guess what was causing my initial confusion was I attempted to convert those 0s to np.nans, which for some reason didn't work (in terms of my mean calc). Hence I was initially wondering if there was something else to it, but appreciate your comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaving this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903305/np-nanmean-not-working-within-a-dataframe/47906712#comment82780712_47903305) from @JohnE here, as a suitable preamble for this post.

> you are fundamentally misunderstanding nan, which means "not a number"
>   like missing data or the result of an invalid operation (e.g. divide
>   by zero). Zero is a valid number (like black is a valid color, I guess
>   ;-) admittedly, zeroes can be interpreted as false by python when
>   numbers are implicitly treated as booleans, but generally speaking,
>   zeroes are valid numbers, and certainly are considered valid for any
>   numerical methods like mean, max, etc.

---

In my opinion, a good solution would involve `mask` -

```
s

0    22.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     0.0
4    35.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

```
s.mask(s.eq(0)).mean()
28.5
```

Or,

```
np.nanmean(s.mask(s.eq(0)).values)
28.5
```

The advantage of this solution is that it works for `Series` as well as `DataFrame` objects.

---

If you have a series (or single column dataframe), the solution simplifies. You could perform boolean indexing to get rid of `0` rows and then call mean.

```
s[s != 0].mean()
28.5
```

Alternatively, call `mean` on the `values`. This should be much faster.

```
i = s.values
i[i != 0].mean()
28.5
```

Comment: Thanks once again, Coldspeed - really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi Coldspeed, they were both really helpful. I found your answer also helped in learning more about the ins and outs of Python, given the different options you mentioned, so have amended accordingly.

Comment: @Foxtrot82 I see... thanks for letting me know. Even though you can accept only one answer, you can upvote them all. Happy holidays.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need replace `0` to `NaN`s and get `mean`s:

```
print (np.nanmean(df.replace(0,np.nan)))
28.5
```

in pandas `NaN`s are omited:

```
print (df)
      a
0  22.0
1   0.0
2   0.0
3   0.0
4  35.0

print (df.replace(0,np.nan).mean())
a    28.5
dtype: float64
```

Comment: It biases mean value. For example take average of (0 + 0+ 4 + 2) instead of (4 + 2). You'll get different values